# Double dollar $$() vs Dollar sign $() in Chrome console behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In our project, there is a different functionality when one Dollar sign used $() in Chrome console vs two Dollar signs $$(), **besides** the known difference that $$() return an array an $() return the first element.

For example, selector for specific element, with one dollar and two dollar queries:

```
$$(".my-class[my-attribute='trump']") //works

$('.my-class[my-attribute=sanders]') //works

$$('.my-class[my-attribute=trump]') //not work
```

What is the source and explanation for this behavior?

Comment: I don't know where you're getting this. 1 and 3 work the same for me. http://i.imgur.com/2YBC2Ad.png (with this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f9teqyo3/)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine yep, it's not reproducible for my as well. I have observed this issue on internal web page we have. Can't really share it...

Comment: Then I'd like to give you a link someone else already gave you :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: We can't really help you otherwise.

Comment: That said, my guess is that your page is using prototype.js which is reusing the `$$` variable.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting point, the project written in Angular. Can it be related?

Comment: Not sure. The best would be looking at `$$.toString()`, I guess.

Comment: In the devtools, it returns: `"function $$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }"`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From [Chrome Developer Tools documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#selecting-elements):

> **Selecting Elements**
>
> There are a few shortcuts for selecting elements. These save you valuable time when compared to typing out their standard counterparts.
>
> $() Returns the first element that matches the specified CSS selector.
> It is a shortcut for document.querySelector().
>
> $$() Returns an array
> of all the elements that match the specified CSS selector. This is an
> alias for document.querySelectorAll()
>
> $x() Returns an array of
> elements that match the specified XPath.

When you use `querySelector` (or `$`), the result is an element or `null`. When you use `$$`, the result isn't an element but an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which can be easily iterated over. This differs from the native `querySelectorAll` where it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is slightly harder to go over all the entries.

Regarding the quote: of course it works the same. See:

[image]

Conclusion: It's useless to quote `trump`. You might also end insane.

Comment: Thanks. So the difference in the need, for example, for apostrophe around attribute value in $$ case in opposite to $ case, from the difference between how querySelector() and querySelectorAll() works?

Comment: @StasS I edited my answer. Does that answer your question ? If it doesn't, please provide more code demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Thanks Denys but i'm asking something a bit different. Edited my code to demonstrate it. There is a syntax that would work in $ case but not in $$. And as far as i understand, there should be some consistency in the underlaying implementation code.

Comment: @StasS You *still* don't provide enough code to reproduce your bug. Are you sure you spotted the last paragraph in my answer ? I think it explains why you have an error: a node list isn't an element.

Comment: I don't have a bug. I'm asking about why the code syntax different between $$ and $. In $ for example, argument value wrapped in apostrophe. In $$, it's not.

Comment: The same syntax works for both functions. Please have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You linked to some internal page :) I assume it's by mistake... regarding the syntax- I can't agree with that, because as displayed in the Q, different syntax work & not work in both cases.

Comment: The link isn't a mistake. What makes your bug impossible to solve is that you don't give enough code to reproduce it.

Comment: But i don't have a bug... If you want to reproduce it, open any webpage, and try to locate element with argument as in the question. It's not a bug, just different behaviors.

Comment: When I test, it works the same for me. Please provide the code example (i.e. the HTML in a fiddle) where it doesnt.

Comment: Can't reproduce it in fiddle. Observed the issue on internal webpage we have.
Nice trump joke :)

Comment: So eventually this behavior occurred do to the frontend framework we work with. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am here in 2017 and can confirm that Trump is indeed useless, have another upvote

Comment: so the `$("...")` function won't work on my .js file without jQuery right? since it is a chrome tool... I was also wondering why `$()` was working on chrome console even on pages without jQuery.

Comment: Technically `$$()` is not an alias for `document.querySelectorAll()`. It's something like `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll())`, because it returns plain javascript array instead of NodeList. That means you can use method like `.map()` or `.filter()` directly from `$$()`.

Comment: Chrome doc link no longer contains this info, but [Utilities  API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities) sub-section does.  See also matching [Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers).