# What is "$" in Chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, console

When we type `$` in chrome console it returns a function. I am sure it's not jQuery's `$`. 
If I want to use jQuery in console, What is the best way to trigger jQuery in chrome console as `$`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$ Variable in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-in-chrome)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682890/double-dollar-vs-dollar-sign-in-chrome-console-behavior

Answer (score 6):

`$` is an [alias for `document.querySelector`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector). In the same vein there is [`$$` which is an alias for `document.querySelectorAll`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselectorall).

It is defined in the Command line (console) api.

#### [Command Line API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselectorall)

> The Command Line API contains a collection of convenience functions for performing common tasks: selecting and inspecting DOM elements, displaying data in readable format, stopping and starting the profiler, and monitoring DOM events.

If you have `$` defined on the page as a global (perhaps by using jQuery), you'll get that global, not the command-line built-in.

There are other [handy functions defined there](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference).

---

To run jQuery, without having it in the page source code, you may find [Chrome extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-injector/ekkjohcjbjcjjifokpingdbdlfekjcgi) to be handy, or simply copy-paste the jQuery source code in the console.

Comment: I don't have jQuery as global then how can I run jQuery as global?

Comment: @JagajitPrusty: If you include jQuery on the page, by default it's global (it defines global `$` and `jQuery` variables). You have to do something intentionally to make it give those up (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: Yeah I know that. I was asking about easy way to do so through some plugin may be such as fireQuery for Firefox.

Comment: @JagajitPrusty If you don't have jQuery as global, `$` will be the same with `document.querySelector`—this is specific to Google Chrome's console, as mentioned. If `window.$` is a function (e.g. `window.$ = function () {}`), that will obviously have higher priority—`$` will not point to `querySelector` but to your function (which can be `jQuery` or whatever you defined).

Comment: @JagajitPrusty To expose jQuery as a global, you just have to do `window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery")` (replace `require("jquery")` with your jQuery function which is not a global). The idea is: by appending it to the `window` object, it becomes a global.

Comment: I don't have jQuery at all. Still I want to run some jQuery code for testing purpose. Then is there any plugin which I can enable so that it will make jQuery global for that tab?

Comment: @JagajitPrusty [Yes, there are extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-injector/ekkjohcjbjcjjifokpingdbdlfekjcgi). Or you can simply copy-paste the jQuery code in the console and run it.