# Why does this Jquery class selector return a function body instead of DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm playing with JQuery writing a chrome extension.

Executing the following class selector

```
 $('.ytp-endscreen-content').children;
```

on a youtube video page in the console returns an HTMLCollection. When the same code runs from a content script in my extension it returns a function definition

[image]

I'm really confused by the behaviour. What am I missing?

Comment: `$(".ytp-endscreen-content")[0].children`

Comment: YouTube is probably not using jQuery. In that case, the `$` is just a shortcut Chrome has mapped to `document.querySelector`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682911/1427878 So in the first case, you are looking at the `children` property of a DOM element, in the second one, at https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Devtools console adds `$` function to all pages which is an alias for document.querySelector. It's not jQuery.

Comment: Firefox does the same. `$` is an alias for `document.querySelector`, and `$$` for `document.querySelectorAll`.