# jQuery: Get text when selector includes elements and text

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the selector `$('div.alert')` I get the following:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
Foo Bar is now locked
</div>
```

I want to return the text `Foo Bar is now locked`. But using `$('div.alert').text()` all I get is `...text() is not a function`. How to retrieve the text?

Comment: The error you describe `text() is not a function` should not occur. Can you make a live example with a Stack Snippet? I think you've copied something wrong from the code you're actually using

Comment: This means `$` does not refer to jQuery constructor. Try with running `jQuery(...).text()` instead.

Comment: Or `$` is not jquery and defined as something else, eg if you're using it in the console, most browsers have `$` defined

Comment: Possibly related, but you're not getting `$` is not defined, but might help: [jquery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Seems like an XY problem (.text is not a function) but to answer your actual question:  you can get the text (without the button) using: `$("div.alert").contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; })[0].nodeValue`  As provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755309/2181514)

Comment: Please check jquery, to do so, add to your js (just before your error line):  `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery); console.log($.fn.jquery)` - please let us know the result.

Comment: @freedomn-m I did not know that "... most browsers have $ defined". Which gives me other directions to go. But my ignorance got a downvote. Hadn't realized that ignorance was to be penalized either.

Comment: To clarify, most browsers have `$` defined *in the console* - more info on `$()` and `$$()` on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682911/2181514).  These are not available/defined on your page.  Looks like you do have the [$ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined) issue.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. The context of the question was to determine a selector to use with Symfony's DomCrawler. I had made the erroneous assumption that I'd already defined jQuery some time ago. So, while more tedious, I'll work within the DomCrawler.